# question about printing only certain values in matrix

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-3, 0, -4], [2, -4, 2], [-2, -2, -2]])
print(X)
```

which generates

```
[[ -3  0  -4]
 [ 2  -4  2]
 [-2 -2 -2]]
```

Now, with this above matrix, I just want to print all the elements in this matrix/array that are positive.

I tried

```
for i in X:
    if i>0
        print(i)
```

But this produces an  syntax error.

Comment: Hi john, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you tell us what the syntax error is? At a glance, your last bit of code is missing a colon.

Comment: try this: `for i in X[X>0]: print(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in np.nditer(X):
    if i>0:
        print(i)
```

You had an error because there is a missing semi-colon after your `if` statement and because the `i` variable is a row of the matrix and not an element.

As described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html), `nditer` returns an efficient multi-dimensional iterator object to iterate over elements of arrays.

Another way to iterate with simple conditions is:

```
for i in X[X>0]:
    print(i)
```

Comment: This is an efficient way to iterate through the element of a multi-dimensional array, as described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html). If you use standard iterators, you will iterate through the sub-dimensions (in your case, a row).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your array has two dimensions. Try something like this:

```
for row in X:
    for column in row:
        if (column > 0):
            print(column)
```

(Also, your syntax error is because you are missing a colon after your if statement)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-3, 0, -4], [2, -4, 2], [-2, -2, -2]])
print(*[i for i in X.ravel() if i>0],sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
2
2
```

[numpy.ravel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) returns flattened (1D) array, you might use it also for higher-dimensioned than `2` arrays.